# EIP4626 Vault Deposit "SafeERC20: low-level call failed"

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, defi

[image]I am trying to write a foundry script that deposits the asset token into a newly deployed EIP4626 Yearn vault.  However, when I try to call the EIP4626 "deposit(uint256)" function on the vault, I get the error message "SafeERC20: low-level call failed". I approve the vault and deposit amount before calling the deposit function, so I don't understand why the transfer is failing.  I have attached an image of the logs.  And the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/popcorndao/sweet-caramel/blob/feature/vaults-v1-forge-scripts/packages/hardhat/contracts/core/forge/VaultsV1Deployment.s.sol) and here:

```
uint256 initialDepositAmount = 1e18; 

 console.log("Deployer asset balance before deposit: ", asset.balanceOf(deployer)); // 1000000000000000000

    console.log("making initial Vault deposit");
    asset.approve(address(vault), initialDepositAmount);
    // Error: "SafeERC20: low-level call failed"
    uint256 shares = vault.deposit(initialDepositAmount);
    if (shares > 0) {[![enter image description here][2]][2]
      console.log("initial Vault deposit complete");
      console.log("Deployer Vault shares: ", shares);
      console.log("Deployer asset balance after deposit complete: ", asset.balanceOf(deployer)); // 0
      console.log("Vault asset balance after deposit complete: ", asset.balanceOf(address(vault))); // 0
    } else if (shares == 0) {
      console.log("initial Vault deposit failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the `approve` function is not successfully finished before calling the `deposit` function.
One way you could try is to `require` the successful approval, and additionally catch any other potential errors with a `trycatch` block:

```js
uint256 initialDepositAmount = 1e18; 

console.log("Deployer asset balance before deposit: ", asset.balanceOf(deployer)); // 1000000000000000000
console.log("making initial Vault deposit");

try {
  // approve token transfer to vault
  bool approvalSuccess = asset.approve(address(vault), initialDepositAmount);
  require(approvalSuccess, "Token approval failed");

  // deposit tokens into vault
  uint256 shares = vault.deposit(initialDepositAmount);
  if (shares > 0) {
    console.log("initial Vault deposit complete");
    console.log("Deployer Vault shares: ", shares);
    console.log("Deployer asset balance after deposit complete: ", asset.balanceOf(deployer)); // 0
    console.log("Vault asset balance after deposit complete: ", asset.balanceOf(address(vault))); // 0
  } else {
    console.log("initial Vault deposit failed");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error occurred during deposit: ", error);
}
```

Maybe this helps!

Comment: thank you! I will try it :D